# Trying to install CloudWatch Agent on Ubuntu 14.04: "Failed to create virtualenv"

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, python, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to install AWS CloudWatch Log Agent on Ubuntu 14.04 following this guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/QuickStartEC2Instance.html

When I type in

```
sudo python ./awslogs-agent-setup.py --region eu-central-1
```

I get the following error:

```
Step 2 of 5: Downloading the latest CloudWatch Logs agent bits ...
ERROR: Failed to create virtualenv. Try manually installing with pip
 and adding it to the sudo user's PATH before running this script.
```

Any tips on how to deal with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

i had the same problem. you can see the logs of the script with:

```
cat /var/log/awslogs-agent-setup.log
```

there were some problems with the locals and a

```
 export LC_ALL=C
```

solved it for me.